# Add array into an associative array using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have an array $items from records in a MySQL database:

```
$result = array();
$result["total"] = 105;

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM users LIMIT 10, 20";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$items = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
```

I want to add this to the associative array $result with the key "rows".

I have tried  this code

**$result["rows"] = $items;**

but print_r($items);  displays nothing.

The json that I want out at the end is:

```
{
   "total":"105",
   "rows":[
      {
         "id":"3",
         "firstname":"fname1234BBBB",
         "lastname":"lname10....",
         "phone":"Lacock 4919999",
         "email":"name991@gmail.com"
      },
```

What am I doing wrong ?  Thanks

Comment: What does `print_r($result)` display ?

Comment: use `$result["rows"][] = $row;` inside the loop

Answer (score 3):

```
    //First don't overwrite $result varaible.
    $result_associative = array();
    $result_associative["total"] = 105;

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM users LIMIT 10, 20";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $items = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
            array_push($items, $row);
           //push the item into array with associative key
        $result_associative['rows'][] = $row;
        }
```

Comment: remove this line inside the loop `array_push($items, $row);`

Comment: @devpro, he might use this variable for something else.

Comment: Thanks Kristiyan - works as I wanted. Thanks for the comment lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
$resultArr = array();
$resultArr["total"] = 105;

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM users LIMIT 10, 20";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    $resultArr["rows"][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($resultArr);
```

Comment: @peter300 welcome dear glad to help you please up vote and accept the helpful answer so that is makes easy for future users to choose the best answer :)